# mymodule.install file not creating the table in drupal 7

Tags: database

I have a very simple table in my .install file and for some reason is not creating the table. What can it be? something i have to add in the .info file? please help.

Its a drupal 7.

this is what i have in my my_module.install file.

```
function my_module_schema() {
  $schema['my_module_config'] = array(
    'description' => 'Configuration settings for the my_module web service.',
    'fields' => array(
      'name' => array(
        'description' => 'Name ',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 50,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '',
      ),
    ),
  );

  return $schema;
}
```

Comment: pls mention your drupal version 6 or 7?

Answer (score 1):

1. you should uninstall the module
2. write the hook_schema function
3. enable the module.

You should also specify the  primary key in the hook_schema

```
 'primary key' => array('field_name'),
```

You can check the drupal [link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7) for the hook_schema

Comment: Disabling / enabling will *not* reinstall the module. You need to uninstall the module (or just nuke it from the system table...)

Comment: yes sorry i meant removing the module completely

Comment: I can not reinstall the module, because the module is not creating any tables anyway. What do you mean removing the module? many thanks.

Comment: there is uninstall option in the modules which removes it from database if previously installed without hook_schema

Answer (score 0):

You should install the schema by invoking the **hook_install** in the **.install** file as follows

```
function modulename_install() {
  drupal_install_schema('my_module_config');
}
```

Comment: No need to call drupal_install_schema as of Drupal 7. check the link :https://api.drupal.org/comment/11769#comment-11769

Comment: This was correct in D6, however.